# Can't set C char array element

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have try set one of array item to specific value. The program is compiled but when I execute it return segfault.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Debug(unsigned char* str, char simbol, char size);


int main() {

  Debug((unsigned char*)"DEBUG: message: x\r\n", 'e', 40);
  return(0);

}

//this function I try to replace all occurrences of x with simbol value 'e'

void Debug (unsigned char* str, char simbol, char size){
    char i;

    for (i = 0 ; i < size ; i++){
        if( str[i] == 'x' ){
            str[i] = simbol;
        }
    }
    printf ("%s\n",  str);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void Debug(unsigned char* str, char simbol, char size);

int main() {
 unsigned char * mumu;
 mumu = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*40);
 mumu = "DEBUG: message: x\r\n";
  Debug(mumu, 'e', 40);
  return(0);

}
void Debug (unsigned char* str, char simbol, char size){
    int i;
    unsigned char * mumu2;
 mumu2 = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*40);
 strcpy(mumu2,str);
 for (i = 0 ; i < size ; i++){
       if( str[i] == 'x' ){
     mumu2[i] = simbol;     
       }}
    printf ("%s\n",  mumu2);
    return;
}

THIS IS A WORKING CODE

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned char* str
```

Here str is read-only and you are trying to write to this location hence segmentation fault.

Have a array

```
unsigned char str[100] = "DEBUG: message: x\r\n";
```

and pass this array to the function.

Comment: Thank you! With predefined array it work perfect.

Comment: @TonyMony Yes that should work...:) You can mark this answered

Answer (score 0):

You try to modify a const object (the string). This is the reason, why you had to cast the string to unsigned char* in the first place. 
To solve this,you have to copy that string into a char array first.